# File Field related issue / How to hide file size information?

Tags: files

I used CDN option while creating my sub-theme. I find less and sass things pretty confusing since I am someone who haven't mastered the css yet. What I have found out so far is:

- I can edit some styling copying some css lines from "/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" to "subtheme/css/style.css" file.

What I want to do is to remove / disable / hide the file size information which shows up next to the file link which is the product of 'file-field' of Drupal. This is viewed using bootstrap's table styling / template or whatsoever you call it.

Is this something that should be accomplished using css or it is a template file or maybe it can only be modified in module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy your parent's theme **file-html.twig** and place in it your subtheme's /templates folder.

Remove line that has `{{ file_size }}`, example:

```
<span class="file-size">{{ file_size }}</span>
```

Flush cache.

Comment: I wish Drupal documentations were as simple as that. Thanks a lot